# Is there any way to create an empty C array, and keep track of its emptyness while updating it?

Tags: c, arrays

I do believe there isn't such thing as an empty `array` in C, I was thinking if we can make them to point to null as in other lenguages, and maybe if some of its' elements has valuable information and then they don't anymore then make them point to nothing again... but I really can't think of any way of doing this.

Comment: No, an array is not a pointer. Please check section 6 of the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: There are no "empty" arrays in C.

Comment: You cannot pass an array in C, only a pointer to the first element, so there is no way for you to tell.

Comment: For generic type? NO. For `char` type, check out `strlen`.

Comment: This is not the way an array works in C. `int a[3];` allocates an array (in this case on stack) with 3 elements. However, the values of these elements are uninitialized but the elements does exist.

Comment: @Scheff `these elements are undefined` --> did you mean the values of them?

Comment: When you call `isEmpty(a)`, a is never `NULL`. Why should it be `NULL`?

Comment: No you can't. Once you allocate memory using `malloc()` if it doesn't fail, the OS will return to you that memory segment. It will contain some garbage in these allocated addresses which are not `NULL`.

Comment: __define "empty"__.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I guess he means not initialized yet.

Comment: @TonyTannous Why'd you consider `malloc()` is success beforehand? :)

Comment: `NULL` is not "emptiness" either (since it's `NULL`). This is a very confused question.

Comment: @unwind Agree to that.

Comment: Thanks @SouravGhosh I guess there's no empty in C, thought it was NULL.

Comment: `NULL` is probably not what you think it is. Read about pointers in your C textbook.

Comment: then **what** is empty in C?

Comment: @newbie On one hand you may (statically or dynamically) allocate some memory. Then you may store how much of it is in practical use. This way "an empty array" may be modelled.

Answer (score 1):

If an array is uninitialized, then there is no way that your program can determine that just based on the array.  You would need to "remember" that information yourself, e.g.:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a[3] ;
    bool a_empty = true;

    // ...
    if ( a_empty )
        printf("a is empty");
    // ...

    a[0] = 1; 
    a_empty = false;
}
```

Another approach would be to define a particular set of contents as representing "empty" (this is called *sentinel values*):

```
#include <stdbool.h>

enum { EMPTY = -1 };

bool is_empty(int a[3])
{
    return a[0] == EMPTY && a[1] == a[0] && a[2] == a[0];
}

int main (void)
{
    int a[3] = { EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY };

    // ...
   if ( is_empty(a) )
        printf("a is empty");
}
```

Of course you would have to choose sentinels that are not valid data for the expected array contents. If no such sentinels exist then you have no choice but to use the extra variable as in my first example.

Comment: In other words: The only way to introduce the concept of an "empty" element is to implement it yourself the way you define a memory to be empty.

Comment: @TonyTannous That's a good summary

Comment: OK so I should tell the array that it is empty before asking it if it is, I thought it could be a library or something, but I guess that would be tricky given the way C has to work with arrays and pointers. Thanks.

Comment: @newbie using `calloc` to allocate memory for `int*`. It sets the whole array to contain `0s`. You could possibly then check if some value isn't equal to `0` but then you won't be able to store `0s` as you won't be able to tell if it is empty or assigned 0.

Answer (score -2):

You might be able to make an empty array and then compare your array too that, if it is the same then the array is empty, else it must have something in it.

```
void isEmpty(int *a)
{
 int compare[3]
    if ( a == compare[2])
        printf("is empty!\n") ;
    else
        printf("not empty!\n");
}

int main (void)
{
    int a[3] ;
    isEmpty(a) ;
    a[0] = 1 ;
    isEmpty(a) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

I haven't had a chance to test this, but have done something similar in PHP before.

Comment: What ? where is compare defined ?

Comment: Inside of the function

Comment: Your answer is wrong.

Comment: You should test code before posting. This will not compile, and `compare[]` is _not_ defined inside the function `isEmpty()`, but only declared. You access this array uninitialized, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidBowling: A declaration of an automatic vriable is also a definition. You are right, though about UB.

Comment: @Olaf-- Hmmm. I better curl up with the Standard, again; thanks for the correction :)